# sass access static image for background-image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, node-sass

I am using `node-sass` in react, and wanted to refer to a static image in my `public` folder, which is not in my `src` folder.

```
background-image: url("/images/icon.png");
```

But the `sass` wouldn't compile saying the image was not found in the `src` folder.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/icon.png'
```

How can I do this? Or how can I make it ignore this check, or make it refer to `public` folder which stores my static filespath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of googling, The only solution I found is to use `~` to reference the very root directory and access the `public` folder from there.

```
background-image: url("~/public/images/icon.png");
```

And this is working fine for me :)

**OR** And the other alternative would be to move images to the `src` directory, and this won't be a problem since webpack would pack them in a folder called `static/media` as static files